# Git: "Missing or invalid task ID in the commit message".Why do I have to provide a task ID?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2010, gitlab

When I do push in Visual Studio, it says in Polish language "Git: Brak lub niepoprawny ID zadania w message'u commita"(translated as "Missing or invalid task ID in the commit message"). I don't know why this git message is in Polish and  Why do I have to provide a task ID.

P.S:I checked my git is connected to GitLab.

Comment: It seems like there's a server-side hook rejecting your push because the commit doesn't have a task ID in the message. Are you following your team's process correctly?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I strongly advise to use English here, so please translate your subject. Others are much less likely to even look at a question they don't understand.

Comment: @SebDieBln: the OP notes that there's no obvious reason the message itself is in Polish, so the Polish may be appropriate here  In any case it translates to "Missing or invalid task ID in the commit message".

Comment: @SebDieBln It looks like the OP is asking why the push is rejected by the remote git responding with a message in Polish. A bit misleading question title though.

Comment: @torek It sure is useful to give the original (polish) message. However using it as the title of the question just leads to many people ignoring the question. The title should be: "Why do I get a polish error message" and maybe (in a second question) "Why do I have to provide a task ID".

Comment: Did you ever find out where this originated from ? I got this out of the blue on a project I'm working on.  No connection to anything polish.  I suspect a Visual Code extension - but can't figure out what extenions or any other reason.

Answer (score 2):

The message "Missing or invalid task ID in the commit message" (as translated into Polish) does not appear in Git itself.  Hence, this message is not coming *from* Git.

It looks like the repository to which you are *sending* the commit is enforcing some rule(s) about commit messages.  When they—the other repository, on the hosting server—reject the message, they send you a message in Polish.  Git can't help you figure out why they don't like your commit message.  You'll need to find that out from somewhere else, probably from the people who run your hosting site.

Comment: @Nithin: no, I can't: I don't use GitLab.